# Running a batch line in VB

Tags: c#, vbscript, batch-file

I am working on automating some batch files that were previous run nightly.  I have the currently set up but since they were originally written as batch files that run batch files it is hard for me to log when and why some of the jobs fail.  I have decided to rewrite these jobs as a C# console application or a vbscript.  I have been running into one big issue in doing this.

the batch file has this line:

```
ctrbld warp7.p < y
```

ctrlbd.exe takes in a file as an argument the warp7.p being the file, but requires a key press of y to start.  In the folder is a y file containing the character y.  I am very much a novice with batch files and cannot figure out how to emulate this action in a vbscript or C# console app.  it always still requires the key press.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Batch **pipes**, or use **Sendkeys** method to send "**Y**" key to the active window (the process).

In Batch:

```
Echo Y|ctrbld.exe warp7.p
```

**In VBS using Batch pipe:**

```
Set Shell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Shell.RUN "CMD /k ""Echo Y|CMD.exe /k Process.exe"""
```

**In VBS using SendKeys:**

```
Set Shell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Shell.RUN "CMD.exe /K"
wscript.sleep(500) ' Wait 500 ms for CMD to fully load, change it if you need more time.
Shell.AppActivate "CMD"
Shell.SendKeys "Y"
```

**In C# using Batch pipe** (Maybe syntax is wrong 'cause I develop on VB.Net)

```
Process.start("CMD.exe", "/K ""Echo Y|CMD /K Process.exe""")
```

**In C# using SendKeys** (Maybe syntax is wrong 'cause I develop on VB.Net)

```
Process.start("Process.exe")
Threading.thread.sleep(500) // Wait for process to load
AppActivate(Handle) // Activate the process window passing a Window Handle
SendKeys.Send("Y")
```

Also like an extra I will give you this function wich I wrote time ago, you can translate it to C# using a online/offline code translator, My code doesn't need to activate the Window to send keys (But only keys, not special keys).

- **In VB.NET using Windows Messages:**

  ```
   #Region " SendKeys To App "

  ' [ SendKeys To App Function ]
  '
  ' // By Elektro H@cker
  '
  ' Examples :
  ' SendKeys_To_App("notepad.exe", "By Elektro H@cker" & vbCrLf & "... :D")

  Private Declare Function FindWindow Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowA" (ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Long
  Private Declare Function FindWindowEx Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowExA" (ByVal hWnd1 As Long, ByVal hWnd2 As Long, ByVal lpsz1 As String, ByVal lpsz2 As String) As Long
  Private Declare Function SendMessage Lib "user32" Alias "SendMessageA" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal wMsg As Long, ByVal wParam As Long, ByVal lParam As String) As Long
  Private Const EM_REPLACESEL = &HC2

  Private Function SendKeys_To_App(ByVal App_Name As String, ByVal str As String) As Boolean
      Dim nPadHwnd As Long, ret As Long, EditHwnd As Long
      Dim APP_WindowTitle As String

      If App_Name.ToLower.EndsWith(".exe") Then App_Name = App_Name.Substring(0, App_Name.Length - 4) ' Rename APP Name

      Dim ProcessArray = Process.GetProcessesByName(App_Name)
      If ProcessArray.Length = 0 Then
          Return False ' App not found
      Else
          APP_WindowTitle = ProcessArray(0).MainWindowTitle ' Set window title of the APP
      End If

      nPadHwnd = FindWindow(App_Name, APP_WindowTitle)

      If nPadHwnd > 0 Then
          EditHwnd = FindWindowEx(nPadHwnd, 0&, "Edit", vbNullString) ' Find edit window
          If EditHwnd > 0 Then ret = SendMessage(EditHwnd, EM_REPLACESEL, 0&, str) ' Send text to edit window
          Return True  ' Text sended
      Else
          Return False ' Name/Title not found
      End If

  End Function

  #End Region
  ```